# How to specify default values for each issue type for custom field on a single project?

Tags: jira, ticket-system

How to specify default value for each issue type for description field on a single project?

I have one project with Scrum board in it. I have issue types: Story, Task, Bug!

When **Analyst** create a new ticket with type "Story" I want to give him predefined text template for full filling:

> Title:
>
> Description:
>
> Explain the business value of the feature:
>
> As <who?>,
>
> I want <what?>
>
> so I can <why?>.
>
> Done conditions:

and I have these template for each issue type.

So how I can configure it?

UPDATE:

Before I wanted to have only one template for all issue types.
So: I have created a custom description field link with project as context and all issue types, and then linked with Field Configuration.

Now I need the different pre defined values for the field for each issue type.
So, I'm trying to created more field contexts to specify them for exact issue type. But those contexts is imposible to link with single project.  Because Jira hide project from the list.

Project A -> Custom field Description -> issue Story -> Value X (Template)

Project A -> Custom field Description -> issue Bug -> Value Y (Template)

Project A -> Custom field Description -> issue Task -> Value Z (Template)